# Может ли фрагмент быть анонимным?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialogfragment

Создал кастомный DialogFragment с доп. методами для быстрого построение диалога из активити.

```
public abstract class ShoppingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder;

public ShoppingDialogFragment setTitle(String title) {
    mBuilder.setTitle(title);
    return this;
}

public ShoppingDialogFragment getBuilder() {
    this.mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    return this;
}

public ShoppingDialogFragment setView(int r) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(r, null);
    mBuilder.setView(v);
    return this;
}

public Dialog create() {
    return mBuilder.create();
}

@Override
public abstract Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState);
}
```

Когда я создаю экземпляр этого класса, студия подчеркивает класс и предупреждает: "Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static"

```
ShoppingDialogFragment shoppingDialogFragment = new ShoppingDialogFragment() {
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return getBuilder().setTitle("test").setView(R.layout.test).create();
            }
        };
        shoppingDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

Приложение работает, но это предупреждение меня смущает. Правильно ли я все сделал и не скажется ли это в дальнейшем на работе приложения?

Comment: А когда телефон ВНЕЗАПНО поворачивается на 90 градусов, что происходит?

Comment: Спасибо, действительно падает.